# Change piece of text using script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change only the word Phone: in the second last line to Tel. in the following code block. The 123-456-7890 would stay after the change. I've tried this different ways and nothing works. Can someone provide me with a JavaScript or jQuery script to do that? Here is the code block.

```
 <div class="staffdirectory imagebase section">
    <div class="staff_member">
    <div class="staff_photo nophoto"></div>
    <div class="staff_name nophoto-name">
    <p><span class="staff_name_bolded">Lname, Fname</span></p>
    <p><span>IT Department</span></p></div>
    <div class="staff_contact nophoto-contact">
    <p>123 Building Center</p>
    <p>Phone: 123-456-7890</p>
    </div><div class="clear_all"></div></div>
```

After the script runs, the resulting HTML would be:

```
   <div class="staffdirectory imagebase section">
   <div class="staff_member">
   <div class="staff_photo nophoto"></div>
   <div class="staff_name nophoto-name">
   <p><span class="staff_name_bolded">Lname, Fname</span></p>
   <p><span>IT Department</span></p></div>
   <div class="staff_contact nophoto-contact">
   <p>123 Building Center</p>
   <p>Tel. 123-456-7890</p>
   </div><div class="clear_all"></div></div>
```

Thank you for your advice!

I've tried:

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#demo').text('The replaced text.');
   });
   </script>
   <div id="demo">
      <p>The initial text</p>
   </div>
```

But I don't want to replace all of the `<p>`, just a piece of it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:contains()` selector to find the `<p>` that has `Phone:` and perform the replacement.

```js
$(".staff_contact p:contains(Phone:)").text(function(i, text) {
    return text.replace('Phone:', 'Tel:');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="staffdirectory imagebase section">
  <div class="staff_member">
    <div class="staff_photo nophoto"></div>
    <div class="staff_name nophoto-name">
      <p><span class="staff_name_bolded">Lname, Fname</span></p>
      <p><span>IT Department</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="staff_contact nophoto-contact">
      <p>123 Building Center</p>
      <p>Phone: 123-456-7890</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear_all"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a `class="PhoneNumber"` to all `<p>` that contain a phone number and then run a simple replace script on them as follows

```
collection = document.getElementsByClassName("PhoneNumber")

Array.from(collection).forEach(element => {
    string = element.innerText.replaceAll("Phone:", "Tel:")
    element.innerText = string
})
```